# Logical operators and looping back through a process in Modelbuilder

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, iterator, eliminate

I am using a series of models in ArcGIS Pro 2.1 to manage gaps and slivers on a very large dataset, and have hit a wall trying to use a logical operator.

I have split the data into multiple smaller datasets within a File Geodatabase and need to iterate through the FGDB to run an Eliminate on any feature classes that have polygons with an area under 0.1 ha.

The model (snapshot attached) uses the If Selection Exists logical operator to continue to the Eliminate process if a selection expression of <0.1 ha exists however the model stops completely if the output is false (i.e. not all feature classes have polygons under 0.1 ha).

How do I get the model to continue to iterate through all the datasets and Eliminate where required without stopping when it hits a dataset that doesn't have polygons under 0.1ha?

[image]

Comment: Something like this http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/if-then-else-branching-and-logical-tools.htm?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelStimson, but that's what I've used... I've added the image now in case you didn't see it at first. I've used If Selection Exists but I cant get it to loop back through the process and continue iterating when the result is false

Comment: Just an idea, replace if selection exists tool with a get count tool and uses its output as a precondition to eliminate.

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd I gave this a quick go but it failed. However I didn't really give it the time it needed as I thankfully had someone create a python script to do all the above which has eliminated (pardon the pun) the need for modelbuilder. It's a shame I couldn't get it running properly though, but with 64 bit Python, I don't even need to split the dataset as it can handle large datasets. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've yet the need to use this tool so I had a tinker with it and it did not behave as I expected, probably us not reading the help file and picking up on some nuance about it is my gut feeling. Logically (pun intended!) it should work...